# how to write customized function that apply to dataframe columns as primitives for DEAP

Tags: deap

I am using DEAP to do symbolic regression. I'm wondering how to write a function that calculate covariance of two columns in python DataFrame of train data as primitives for symbolic regression? The examples are all applying functions to rows of train data.
can any one help me with this question?
thank you!

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried to do? Have you tried to replace the data structure in those examples with the data structure you want to use?

Comment: My train data is a 3-dimension tensor: (sample, timesteps, features). I would like to apply both time series functions and cross-sectional functions to each sample. For example, an individual function is func, for each sample I have func([timesteps, features]), and the func return only one float